# Добавить constraints который будет управлять Foreign Key в зависимости от значений поля в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица `Documents` в которой хранятся документы сохраненный под какой-то конкретный target

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | Name | Target |
+----+------+--------+
```

И есть таблица `Customers`, в которой соответственно хранятся данный клиентов.

Нужно добавить в таблицу `Documents` поле `CustomerId` и связать это поле с соответствующей записью в таблице Customers, но только тогда, когла значение `target = 1`.

Как правильно реализовать данную задачу?

Добавление поля `CustomerId` и заполнение его я сделал, вопрос только в реализации `foreign key`.

Нужно добавить `constraint`, который на каждый `alter` или `insert` будет проверять значение `target` и делать запрос в таблицу `Customers`?

Или, может, можна как то управлять `FK` через `constraint`?

Когда `target` не равно 1 - `CustomerId` должно быть `null`.

Comment: *Когда target не равно 1 - CustomerId должно быть null* - значит, в реферальной таблице нужно добавить запись (а хоть бы и фэйковую), где референсное поле имеет значение Null. Тогда констрейнт получается простейший - `CASE WHEN target=1 THEN CustomerId IS NOT NULL ELSE CustomerId IS NULL END`. Ну и плюс FK, сабо самой. PS. Надеюсь, на поле не наложено требование уникальности (без учёта NULLов)?

Comment: Это плохая идея добавлять фейковую запись для решения данной задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ValidateDocumentsToCustomers](
    @TargetId INT,
    @CustomerId INT
) RETURNS INT
BEGIN  
DECLARE @Result INT;
IF(@TargetId = 1)
    SET @Result = 1
ELSE
    SET @Result = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT Customers.Id
                FROM Customers
                WHERE Customers.Id = @CustomerId
            )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END;
    RETURN ISNULL(@Result, 0)
END
GO


ALTER TABLE Documents ADD CONSTRAINT Documents_ValidateDocumentsToCustomers
    CHECK (dbo.ValidateDocumentsToCustomers(TargetId, CustomerId) > 0)");
```